# How do I commit my changes to a project?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I've cloned the original repository, made some changes in it then forked the original to my account. Now I'm kind of lost. How do I contribute to the original repository? I can't send these changes to my fork, since the project is connected to the original and I don't have direct permissions to contribute.

Comment: It sounds like you have a local clone of the original repository and a fork on github but that you have not yet added your fork as a git remote in your local repo. If you run `git remote -v` it will list your remotes (the remote repositories) you've told git about and therefore the places you can push to. If the default `origin` remote is currently pointing to the original repo you probably want to remove that and add your fork instead. Then you can push to your fork and create a pull request from there.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize it was that simple, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to submit a pull request to the owner of the repo.

Check this out! It has a clear illustration on how to contribute via fork.
https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you, that looks helpful. I'll read the rest later, now I'm not sue how to push changes to my own fork instead of the original. Since I cloned the original, and made some changes there `git push` will attempt to push it to the original, can I somehow redirect that to my fork instead?

Edit: Is that what Step 3 describes?

Comment: Yes! Did you try navigating to your fork and commit changes? If not so commit the changes navigating to your fork and update your repo.

Comment: Thank you! Seems that I was misunderstanding the way it all works. I shouldn't search for a way to commit my changes, I just have to wait for the owner to approve of them lol